# Data Explorer para Stack Overflow en español

Tags: característica-nueva, data-explorer

Segun [esta](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/404472/ultima-acutializacion-de-data-stackexchange) query, Data Explorer fue actualizado por ultima vez, hoy a las 0:00 hs.

Aun no aparece Stack Overflow en español.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Se puede agregar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primero, los nuevos sitios de la semana pasada no entran en SEDE hasta el lunes siguiente.

Segundo, SEDE no incluye los sitios que todavía están en sus betas privadas. Hay que esperar a que estemos en la beta pública.

Answer (score 3):

Ya estamos en la beta pública y ya aparece SOes en [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

[image: SOes en SEDE]